# Spring Aggregator Annotation doesnot have expireGroupUponCompletion and persistenceStore as input

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-annotations

I recently moved to Spring boot and started converting all the XMLs to Java Configs. The @Aggregate annotation does not have expireGroupUponCompletion and persistenceStore as the input. Is there any other way we can specify these things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any other way we can specify these things?

Using [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#aggregators):

```
.aggregate(a -> a.expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                 .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                 .messageStore(messageStore(), null)
```

The second `null` param means that we aren't interested in some `endpoint` customization and just rely on the defaul state. We left that syntax to avoid the explicit type for Lambda argument:

```
.aggregate((AggregatorSpec a) -> a.expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                 .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                 .messageStore(messageStore())
```

Comment: But now if I add .sendPartialResultsOnExpiry(true) to the above chain, the code is not compiling :( And what does null at the end means?

Comment: Sorry i got it. I have to use .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)

Comment: Added explanation to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Artem.I am able to solve the problem with the following configuration.

```
    @Bean
public IntegrationFlow pollingFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(splitSegment())
                           .aggregate( a -> a
                                     .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                                     .messageStore(persistenceMessageStore())
                                     .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                                     .discardChannel(aggregateSegments())
                                     .correlationStrategy(m -> m.getPayload())
                                     .releaseStrategy(g ->  g.getMessages().size() > 5)
                                     .outputProcessor(g -> {
                                                               CountDB ag = new CountDB();
                                                               ag.setId((Long) g.getOne().getPayload());
                                                               ag.setActiveUsers((long)g.getMessages().size());
                                                               return ag;
                                                            })
                                    ,
                                     null)
                           .channel(aggregateSegments())
                           .get();
```